# Problem of xepersian with beamer in TexLive 2023

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xetex, xepersian

the following code ([from my previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678736/241755)) without `xepersian` package works fine but when I add `xepersian` package it doesn't show the logo! (it was Ok using TexLive 2022)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{devryblue}{RGB}{5, 51, 92}    
\makeatletter
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{devryblue}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usepackage{default}  

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (logo) at ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east);
\fill[devryblue] (logo) circle (.9cm);
\clip (logo) circle (.75cm);
\node at (logo) {\includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{My Title}
    some text about Latex
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `bidi` package, which gets loaded by `xepersian` will change the frametitle template from the default left aligned one to a right aligned frametitle -- and it will do this not when the package is loaded but only after the document has already started. This means you will have to delay your own changes until after this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{devryblue}{RGB}{5, 51, 92}    
\makeatletter
\colorlet{beamer@blendedblue}{devryblue}
\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usepackage{default}  



\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

\section{title}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (logo) at ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north east);
\fill[devryblue] (logo) circle (.9cm);
\clip (logo) circle (.75cm);
\node at (logo) {\includegraphics[width=2.1cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\tableofcontents

\end{frame}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{My Title}
    some text about Latex
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for finding a solution! I want to add some comments to this problem and your solution: `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` and `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}` should be called after `begin{document}` in TexLive 2023 and `xepersian` package.